# Logging Visitor Email Addresses

Tags: php, html, iframe

Find and display website visitors email :

Display a visitors email. **Gmail** displays as page/tab title `"Inbox (number) email@gmail.com - Gmail"`

I frame on main site, redirect I frame to gmail - pull I frame page title.

Trying to keep this as simple as possible Invisible I frame redirect grab page title :

```
document.write('<iframe src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/home.html?title='+document.title+'&url='+window.location+'" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do AND I don't see any PHP code to go with the PHP tag, so if this is really a PHP problem then include the relevant code (which may explain what you are trying to do) and if not then remove the PHP tag.

Comment: You would like to retrieve the gmail-address of your visitors by including an iframe in your website? No, this is not possible. Should be a HUGE security risk if it would. Google for 'same origin policy' for more infromation. If you want their e-mailaddress, ask politely for it.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't come as a huge surprise that you can't do that.

The same-origin policy prevents you from reading any information from a frame that's *currently* displaying a page from another domain (a "cross-origin frame"). You can't get around that with a redirect.

Comment: I managed to get it done through facebook using their apps.facebook.com system.